# change log4j property file at runtime cause an empty default log created

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I have an application that uses log4j to log on a text file, i have placed a log4j.properties file inside my executable jar file containing the default log configuration parameters.

My log4j.properties file looks like the following :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] - %m%n
```

My application have also a command line option that allow the user to change the log file name, so i have a function like the following that change the settings of log4j at runtime :

```
public void changeLogFileName(String filename) {    
          props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1","org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender");
          props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern","'-'ddMMyyyy");
          props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1.File",filename);
          LogManager.resetConfiguration();
          PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
    }
```

*Everything work fine, unless when the statement **LogManager.resetConfiguration()** and/or **PropertyConfigurator.configure(props)**  are executed a default empty log file (mylogfile.log) is automatically created.* 
After that everything i log from my application will be written correctly in the new file, but an empty file is created anyway (with the name of the default log filename in the log4j.properties).

*Is there a way to avoid the creation of the empty default log file ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally developed [log4j-additions](https://code.google.com/p/log4j-additions/) library that allow the creation of a Lazy initialization appender that avoid the creation of the empty log file.

## log4.properties

```
#Lazy File Appender
log4j.appender.A1=org.pollerosoftware.log4j.additions.appenders.LazyFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File=juakaritoglory.log
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] - %m%n
```

## Method to change the path

```
/**
 * Change the path of log file
 * @param path new path
 */
public synchronized void changeLogPath(String path) {
      String filename = (path.endsWith(File.separator)) ? path : path + File.separator;
      filename += LOGFILENAME + "-{timestamp}.log";

      props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1","org.pollerosoftware.log4j.additions.appenders.TimestampFileAppender");
      props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1.TimestampPattern","ddMMyyyy");
      props.setProperty("log4j.appender.A1.File",filename);
      LogManager.resetConfiguration();
      PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
}
```