# log4cplus - how do I change the log file name at runtime?

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I'd like to have several related programs use the same log4cplus configuration file but each write to a different filename. That way the log files go into the same place, are the same size and use the same internal format (etc).

log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator doesn't expose the "find this option and change it" methods that I suspect might work, and I'm reluctant to play with the source code until I'm sure there's no other way.

In log4j that's easy [using system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953207/2411937) and there's an [extension to make it even easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053684/change-log4j-property-file-at-runtime-cause-an-empty-default-log-created), but I can't see how to do the same in log4cplus.

I'm using NetBeans/G++ 4.7.3/C++11/Ubuntu if that's helpful to know.